# Invalid Syntax issue in python string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have the following code running on a docker container. When I run without docker container its working perfectly fine but when I run on docker container I receive invalid syntax. Python version on the docker container is 3.5 while on the machine is 3.6

```
print(f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} ( i ) :  Switching to {current_server}...")
```

Error:

```
File "client.py", line 21
print(f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} ( i ) :  Switching to 
{current_server}...")
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks, help is highly appreciated, how to solve this formatting issue.

Comment: Please include the error stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f-strings are introduced in python 3.6 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). Hence, running a Python 3.5 in docker is probably the cause of your problem.